# How to rename elements of a column based on conditions of a different column elements in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
data1               data2
5044236896589556        network7
5044236754695813        network23
5214796523415689        english
0               hispanic
5879654132659965        network18
5044236569584213        Telugu
```

I am trying to rename all those elements in data2 if the adjacent element in data1 starts with '504423' to Telugu. I have tried using .loc method but was not successful.

I am trying to achieve this as an output.

```
data1               data2
5044236896589556        Telugu
5044236754695813        Telugu
5214796523415689        english
0               hispanic
5879654132659965        network18
5044236569584213        Telugu
```

As always your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly how is this data represented in your code? Also, what was the error when you ran your code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is under variable `df` try this:

If `data1` is string (`dtype object`)

```py
df.loc[list(map(lambda x: x.startswith("504423"), df["data1"])), "data2"]="Telugu"
```

If `data1` is not string

```py
df.loc[list(map(lambda x: str(x).startswith("504423"), df["data1"])), "data2"]="Telugu"
```